# Can't convert String to DateTIme

Tags: c#, date, datetime

My Date Format : 12/30/2014 12:00:00 AM (MM/dd/yyyy) and I have a string rep as

```
String DateOfIssue = "12/30/2014 12:00:00 AM";

DateTime DOI = DateTime.ParseExact((DateOfIssue).Trim(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

but it is throwing exception. I have seen a lot of posts on SO but none is working. What am I doing wrong ? Please help and point my error. I have tried en-US also but that is also not working.

when I remove `tt` every thing works fine.

Comment: [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`HH` - is for 24 hours format, use `hh` instead:

```
DateTime DOI = DateTime.ParseExact((DateOfIssue).Trim(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Comment: Further:  the problem is that 12:00:00 AM is a 12-hour representation.  The 24-hour version would have been 00:00:00.